# jQuery: Chain selectors off of DOM element variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have this event handler from kendo's drag and drop  [UI](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/draggable)  and I've assigned it to a variable, lets say e.

I'm trying to select divs that have ID's containing a certain string. I know the syntax for that when continuing from classic jQuery selectors, i.e.

```
$('select div[id*="whatever"]')
```

But can I do this off of a variable that contains a DOM element? I know this is a rather simple question but google has thus far been unable to help me.

Comment: Yes, you just put the variable in the jQuery object - `$(variable)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter a preexisting jQuery result, you can go with this:

```
var $allDivs = $("div"),
    $certainDivs = $allDivs.filter("[id*='whatever']");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might want [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
// returns all DOM elements that
// (1) are descendants of e
// (2) match the selector
e.find("selector");
```

If `e` isn't wrapped with jQuery, you might need to do `$(e)` instead.

Comment: Find looks into the **descendants** of the given collection.

Comment: @randombumper I might have misunderstood the question then.

Comment: What's funny is I found this answer while google searching to solve the problem that this answer solves.